# Label orientation in an R plot

Tags: r, plot, label

How can I get label orientation as in the plot below:

[image]

Comment: Can we have a bit of reproducible code please (e.g. a data set that produces almost what you want but with the wrong text orientation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
barplot(c(3,2,1), horiz=TRUE, las=2, names.arg=c("three", "two", "one"))
```